# How to skip to next "elseif" in PHP statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

If you have an if/else statement like the one below, is there a way to check something inside the first matching `if` and tell it to skip ahead to the next `else/if`, and do this multiple times?

`continue` seemed promising after some googling, but didn't work so maybe that's only for loops

```
if ($teamscore > 100) {
    if ($somethingelse=$something) {
        //skip to the next "elseif"
    }
} elseif ($teamscore > 95) {
    if ($somethingelse=$something) {
        //skip to the next "elseif"
    }
} elseif ($teamscore > 90) {

} else {
}
```

Comment: Refactor the code so that the additional condition is factored in, e.g.: `if($teamscore > 100 && $somethingelse !== $something) { ... }` ?

Comment: make the condition bodies into functions, then call the execution within whatever applicable condition

Comment: If you are IN the IF you will NEVER get into any of the ELSEIF's thats what an if/elseif does. it does ONLY ONE of the possibilities

Comment: Are you in some kind of loop? If so show us. Without a loop I am note sure I understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you told us what you are trying to achieve. Then this may all start to make sense

Comment: Probably only a typo in your example, but `$somethingelse=$something` doesn't compare the variables. It will set `$somethingelse` to `$something`. It should be `$somethingelse == $something` (two equal signs). When your question is kind of abstract, it's even more important that the examples are spot on or it will be even more confusing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly not a loop - `but didn't work so maybe that's only for loops` and I read it as "I want to trigger the code for another condition from another condition" ... but maybe not(?) - posted an answer but maybe I should wait for an edit?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for your comment about "NEVER getting into the others" thats what I didn't know was possible or not, but sounds like not. And sorry for not explaining more. Long story short is I'm not in a loop. It's just a standalone if/else and I've noticed that the code overlooked something and now am trying to add a quick fix to prevent rewriting all code, which I should probably consider anyway

Comment: @CD001, thanks, i think that's what I might have to do in this case, temporarily at least.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, yep, just a typo, thanks for looking out tho!

Answer (score 2):

It seems  like what you're going for is sort of like a [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), but you can't evaluate separate expressions in each `case`, so you can't use it for inequalities like this. I think this structure could be used instead.

```
while (true) {
    if ($teamscore > 100) {
        // DO STUFF
        if ($somethingelse != $something) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($teamscore > 95) {
        // DO STUFF
        if ($somethingelse != $something) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($teamscore > 90) {
        // DO STUFF
        if ($somethingelse != $something) {
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

However, if `// DO STUFF` is the same thing in each if block, or a variation of the same thing that fits a pattern, you probably could use a loop instead to avoid the repetition.

```
for ($score = 100; $score > 85; $score -= 5) {
    if ($teamscore > $score) {
        // DO STUFF
    }
    if ($somethingelse != $something) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should turn your condition bodies (in my example, the `echo`'s) into functions:

```
if ($foo == 'bar') {
    echo 'it is bar!';
} elseif ($foo == 'foobar') {
    echo 'it is is foobar!';
} else {
    echo 'it\'s nada!';
}
```

becomes:

```
function sayBar()
{
    return 'it is bar!';
}

function sayFooBar()
{
    return 'it is foobar!';
}

function sayNada()
{
    return 'it\'s nada!';
}

if ($foo == 'bar') {
    echo sayBar();

    if ($bar == 'Treybake is awesome') {
        echo sayFooBar();
    }
} elseif ($foo == 'foobar') {
    echo sayFooBar();
} else {
    echo sayNada();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for somthing like this,

```php
if ($teamscore > 100 && $somethingelse !== $something) {

} elseif ($teamscore > 95 && $somethingelse !== $something) {

} elseif ($teamscore > 90 && $somethingelse !== $something) {

} else {
}
```